# Animate hamburger icon to arrow back in toolbar

Tags: android

Im looking for the best practice to animate the hamburger icon to arrow back in toolbar.

Comment: Do not post question as like in some other apps . Except this Read [ask] and ask question properly .

Comment: @ADM Man, i mentioned other app for more clearly understanding my question. Maybe you can give an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the answer by myself

```
protected void setHomeAsUp(boolean isHomeAsUp){
            ValueAnimator anim = isHomeAsUp ? ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 1) : ValueAnimator.ofFloat(1, 0);
            anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                    float slideOffset = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                    actionBarDrawerToggle.onDrawerSlide(drawerLayout, slideOffset);
                }
            });
            anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
            anim.setDuration(400);
            anim.start();
        }
```

Comment: May I ask where did the "actionBarDrawerToggle" come from?